# Cassandra data stax Query Builder Update

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am trying to write a simple Update query - Update table set col1 = val1, col2 = val2 where col3 = val3; Can you please provide an example of writing a simple UPDATE in Cassandra using the Query builder API?

Answer (score 11):

Try this out.

v1.x:

```
Query exampleQuery = update("table").with(set("col1", "val1")).and(set("col2","val2")).where(eq("col3","val3"));
```

v2.x:

```
Statement exampleQuery = update("table").with(set("col1", "val1")).and(set("col2","val2")).where(eq("col3","val3"));
```

Patrick

Comment: Enjoy your first "Nice Answer" badge!

Answer (score 0):

I used this for Scala

```
QueryBuilder.update(keyspace_name,table_name).where(eq(column,value)).\`with\`(set(col1, val1)).and(set(col2,val2)).and(set(col3,val3));
```

P.S.: Don't forget to import `eq` and `set` from  `com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.QueryBuilder`.