# Datastax java-driver QueryBuilder.update issue in scala

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Here is the scala code I am attempting to use to update a row in a cassandra database:

```
 val query = QueryBuilder.update("twitter","tweets")
             .`with`(QueryBuilder.set("sinceid", update.sinceID)
             .and(QueryBuilder.set("tweets", update.tweets)))
             .where(QueryBuilder.eq("handle", update.handle));
```

which is based off of the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557110/cassandra-data-stax-query-builder-update)

Everything seems to work correctly except for the ".and". The error I get back is

```
value and is not a member of com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Assignment
```

Which, of course, is true, but at that point in the statement it should be using

```
com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Update.Conditions
```

Which contains the and()

Thank you for your help

Comment: Shouldn't it be something more like: `.where(QueryBuilder.eq("handle", update.handle).and(QueryBuilder.set("tweets", update.tweets))))`?

Comment: The compiler still doesnt recognize the '.and' in this case, though the error message is different "value and is not a member of com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Clause
"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have your parentheses mismatched, you are getting the error because `and` is not a member of `Assignment` which is what `QueryBuilder.set("sinceid", update.sinceId)` returns.  You need to add an extra parentheses after `sinceId)` so the `.and` chains off of `.with` which returns `Assignments` which has an `and` method.

The following works for me:

```scala
val query = QueryBuilder.update("twitter","tweets")
  .`with`(QueryBuilder.set("sinceid", update.sinceID))
  .and(QueryBuilder.set("tweets", update.tweets))
  .where(QueryBuilder.eq("handle", update.handle))
```

Comment: I read your response and put my head on the desk for 5 minutes. That's right, thank you.